# terraform tfstate is not refreshing from remote s3 bucket

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i deployed AWS infrastructure using the tf code on my local machine which stored the terraform.tfstate on my machine. now i want other developers to refer the same state file and hence i copied the code to github repo and added state.tf and copied the terraform.tfstate from my local machine to s3 bucket prefix that my state file is pointing to. i also one changes in the repo, instead of having one large tf file i divided it into three files - state.tf, vpc.tf and dynamodb.tf.

my state.tf file:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
   bucket = "testing-d-tf-state"
   key    = "aws-xyz/terraform.tfstate"
   region = "us-west-2"
  }
}
```

however, when my developer is running the code on his machine he is getting

> Plan: 26 to add, 0 to change, 25 to destroy.

I am unable to figure out why he is not getting the terraform.tfstate file refreshed correctly to read such that he does not get "add" or "destroy" as there is no change made to the infrastructure.

Comment: That looks like they are getting some state at least because Terraform knows there are 25 resources to destroy. Are you sure your state file is configured correctly and you're not looking at the wrong state file?

Comment: thanks for the reply @ydaetskcoR.  i am looking at the correct state file. The only difference is that in my github code i am using bash script to create terraform workspace so that i can deploy the code in multi regions by having "aws-xyz/terraform.tfstate" for each region. I am passing AWS_REGION=us-west-2 as the environment variable and on my s3 bucket i have manually created the `us-west-2/aws-xyz` folders and uploaded the terraform.tfstate to it.  i also have .terraform/environment file having `us-west-2`

Comment: my state file works fine if i newly create the infrastructure and if i re run the code on that then i dont get the "add" or "destroy" message. The "add" or "destroy" is only coming if i try to use the state file that i copied from my local machine and using that in the new code/folder structure. any idea what i could be doing wrong? any pointers would be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't manually copy the `terraform.tfstate` file to the remote location. After you've coded up the `backend` info, you would re-run `terraform init` and Terraform will take care of setting that up correctly for you both locally and in the remote bucket.

After you've done this, there are a few things you should do to confirm it worked:

1. Log into the AWS console and confirm that there is now a `terraform.tfstate` file in the correct bucket & location.
2. move the local `terraform.tfstate` file (don't delete it yet just in case), then running something like `terraform state list` that will query the state file. If it works, then your remote state config is working.

Comment: Thanks @KJH, i even tried that and also terraform state push -force  terraform.tfstate.backup but no luck i am still getting `Plan: 26 to add, 0 to change, 25 to destroy.`. the one difference i forgot to mention is that in the new code i am using terraform workspace while in the old code (having terraform.tfstate) i  was not using the workspace. now the question how can i port the state file to workspace?

Comment: Ah, it's the switch to TF workspaces that's causing this. I re-read your comment and see that you're using workspaces for different regions. I've only considered using workspaces for environments (e.g. prod, dev, test, etc.), and that's what TF originally envisioned it for. What if your wrapper script didn't use `terraform workspace`, but just injected the region into the backend info? Would that give you enough variable & state isolation?

Comment: i tried running it without workspace and even then i am getting the same add or destroy message. there is one more change in my new code. earlier i was using module something like this `module "vpc" {
  source = "/dtest"
  home_dir = "/Users/deepak.prasad/"
  aws_profile = "dtest"
  s3_bucket = "<bucketname>"
 }` but now i am not using any module. would that be an issue? sorry i am still naive to terraform...

Comment: @DeepakPrasad - unfortunately at this point, someone would have to see *all* of your TF code, your wrapper script, the errors you're seeing, etc. to get to the bottom of the problem and come up with a solution. One thing I would strongly recommend is don't add additional changes (like the module change) along the way - that just compounds the problem.